# Responsive Grid View appearing in single column

Tags: views, theming

I'm trying to create a responsive views grid. I installed the the [Views Responsive Grid](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_responsive_grid) module. The problem is when I select that option the images appear in a single column instead of appearing in the specified columns. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to apply some css rules to the output. Basically, assuming each div of the grid has a `views-content` class, give that class a `float:left` and some margin. Or if you use a responsive theme already, set the correct classes to the output in Views UI...

As per the [Views Responsive Grid](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_responsive_grid):

> In order for the columns to work you'll need to specify the class name
>   of your columns. For example, if your theme utilizes a grid, like
>   Twitter Bootstrap does, you would specify "span3" as the column
>   class(making sure to use the correct span size). This will make sure
>   your column adhere to the grid in your Bootstrap based theme.